# Standard report missing critical data

Tags: finance, sap-erp

for one of our customer localized in Spain, we need to manage their Legal Tax Report(*model 347*), currently processed by the standard SAP-ECC report `RPFIES_M347`(which is run by transaction code `FIES_M347`).

I'm no financial expert and the scope of this answer doesn't involve finance at all. However, I found this guide about this report and how it works and I found it useful. Here's the link: [SAP Model 347 Report](https://www.se80.co.uk/sapreports/r/rpfi/rpfies_m347.htm).

---

#### ***The problem***

The problem I'm facing is critical. Although this is a report is run once a year, it must be fixed, either by us or by SAP itself(in case this is an unknown issue).

This Report does work, it prints out a list of documents created on a specific year and all the information exist. The main issue though, is that this data is not consistent. There is this one field that isn't always filled correctly(either is empty or filled correctly).

The field in question is the `Business Partner Tax ID`(or `VAT Number`).

Here's a picture showing that the field is not filled for some documents(5th column from right):
[image]

And here's the input I gave to the report at selection screen:
[image]

[image]

Now, the document/entry I showed(first screenshot) doesn't have the field `Business Partner Tax ID` filled.

The below image is of the same document

Side note: Some Business Partners do not have their Tax ID configured, but we're not actually worried about those because they just don't have a Tax ID.

Some BPs though, do have their Tax ID configured.

This is a screenshot of the two documents showed in the first screenshot. This time I just changed a think at selection screen.

Here's the output:

[image]

And here's the input:

[image]

Note: The only thing I changed here is the document numbers's range.

Document numbers in the first and in the second image are the same, though in one output the filled isn't filled and in the other it is filled.

One particular thing that happened and that makes the report work as intended is when we add or change data of a BP.

To do this, navigate to transaction code **`BP`** with a BP number that does have the Tax ID set but is not showing in the report and navigate to `Identification` tab. The last panel(the one titled `Tax Numbers` stores all Tax ID of the selected BP.

This is ours:

[image]

Now, if we add the below entry to one row of this section, that report's field is somehow and for some reason is filled.

The entry we added to fix the problem is: `Category=ES1` and `TaxNumber={tax_number}`

Although this does solve the issue, it's not the one we want.

---

#### ***Useful Info***

- `SAP_BASIS Version = 752`
- The problem occurs both in Development and Production, meaning that this is not data related!
- The BP I showed you are neither archived nor deleted, so no possibility of Audit data being used.
- The problem occurs independently of the country code(ES,IT,FR,DE, etc...)
- The problem doesn't occurs(for some BPs) if we make a selection of their documents at selection screen.

---

#### ***Notes***

I cannot show everything of the output for obvious reason. If you need debugging traces or anything I'll see what I can do!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to the issue I was having with report `FIES_M347`.

It turns out that the report's code works like this:

- Reads all documents, based on a set of criteria, from DB table `BSEG`.
- Loops through this table and check if the document is to be taken into account or not.
- In the mean time, the details of the first row of the document is saved into an internal table called `GT_CUST`, which stores all details of a specific BP, one of which is the VAT Number/Tax ID.( Note: This data is stored even if the document does not match some criteria).
- If the BP has more than one document, the report will try to read from `GT_CUST` first, and if it contains this data already, it'll use it, thus if the Tax ID isn't present already, it'll not be shown on the report.

Our problem wasn't with the report as I thought it would be, but with our data.

As a matter of fact, it turns out that after a data migration, some fields like Tax ID, weren't properly migrated, thus creating this problem.